# Is it OK to have an exhaust fan directly above the intake fan for the CPU heatsink?

Tags: fan, cooling, computer-building

I've been assembling a custom PC, and was wondering if it's OK to have an exhaust fan directly above the intake fan for my heatsink.

This is how my system is laid out

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be alright?

Comment: I was just thinking it would "rob" the heatsink of air. I currently have 3 exhaust fans and 1 intake fan (the heatsink, PSU, and GPU have their own intake fans, of course).

Comment: What is in your picture looks fine.

Comment: Inlined your image. I resized it for you, and I suspect some arrows showing airflow direction would be useful here.

Comment: @CullenJ - You don't want hot air in your case.  So if you are extracting air, what air your heatsink does have access too, will be cooler than the air your extracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be okay to put but it is of no use to connect the exhaust fan on an intake fan, both will be fighting for the same air(i.e. neither hot nor cool) as both are in the same direction. instead of that put both the intake fan at one place.

That is remove your 1 intake fan and connect it above the CPU intake fan so that the external intake fan bring the cool and fresh air inside the cabinet and your CPU intake fan will take that air directly not any other hot air.

[image: push pull fan]

And your other fans (exhaust fans) will do there job of removing hot air from the cabinet.

Direction of the Air matters a lot see this design architecture of this cabinet then you will get a clear picture.

[visit this for more infor](http://www.overclock.net/t/1204530/official-phantom-410-mid-tower-owners-club/4120#)
[image: Cabinet]
**Edit**
[image: cpu fan]
your connection are okay but my advice is to Change the marked exhaust fan with intake fan that will be good for giving cool air to your CPU.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I was clear enough. I wish I could post a pic from my phone. So here's my situation. I have my heatsink intake pointing toward the rear of the PC. I have an exhaust fan 90° above the heatsink intake, pointing up to the top of the PC. Are you saying these will be fighting against each other?

Comment: No,If your fan is facing toward the rear of the PC and have angle of 90° then it will be perfectly okay. I thought that you are connecting it exactly opposite to your CPU fan.

Comment: Okay I have edited my anwer

Comment: I wouldn't swap the top fan to intake, I'd stick with in at bottom & front, out at top & rear. The current layout from the OP's pic is fine, so long as there is sufficient intake that we can't see. The disputed fan is actually going to be pulling cooler air from the bottom of the case, allowing the heat sink fans to use that cool air.

Comment: @ali786, Your advice in your edit is exactly what I ended up doing; so far, I'm very happy with the results I'm seeing in SpeedFan now. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are saying. The top fan is fighting the CPU fan for air as the top fan is sucking available air out. This is my own experience. When I had the top blowing in temps where good and fans quiet. I reversed it and made the top exhaust as that seemed a great way to get top hot air out. No hot air comes out the top but the back is hot. It is loud up top as fan struggles to blow any air out. Dust is better but temps and noise where better with it blowing in from the top. I may move it over to the other top slot (one fan in mine) and see. If not it is back to blowing in right on the CPU fan as this seemed much better.